# Does Oracle Nosql Cloud Service have provision to set max read units consumption per second?

Tags: oracle-nosql

Does Oracle Nosql Cloud Service have provision to set max read units consumption per second. For e.g. In 40K read units, I want to reserve 20K for 1st operation and rest 20K for 2nd operation. In order to make sure 20K is always reserved for 1st operation, I want to set max read units consumption per second for 2nd operation. Is this something possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provision values are for the entire table, so if a table has 40K read units /second, it’s up to the application to apportion them per operation.The SDKs have rate limiting support that can help with this. For example, see https://oracle.github.io/nosql-java-sdk/oracle/nosql/driver/NoSQLHandleConfig.html#setDefaultRateLimitingPercentage(double).

> Sets a default percentage of table limits to use. This may be useful
> for cases where a client should only use a portion of full table
> limits. This only applies if rate limiting is enabled using
> setRateLimitingEnabled(boolean).

You could use this method in your case.